# Number of bits in Javascript numbers

Tags: javascript

I work in Javascript with integer numbers only (mainly adding numbers and shifting them). I wonder how big they can be without loosing any bits.

For example, how big `X` can be such that `1 << X` will represent `2^X` ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-to

Answer (score 41, accepted):

All numbers in JavaScript are actually IEEE-754 compliant floating-point doubles. These have a 53-bit mantissa which should mean that any integer value with a magnitude of approximately 9 quadrillion or less -- more specifically, 9,007,199,254,740,991 -- will be represented accurately.

---

NOTICE: in 2018 main browsers and NodeJS are working also with the new Javascript's primitive-type, [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), solving the problems with integer value magnitude.

Comment: @Revanth: Almost! The maximum integer that can be represented accurately is `(2^53)-1` or `9,007,199,254,740,991`. In practice, `2^53` will evaluate as `9,007,199,254,740,992` but this isn't, in theory, an accurate representation because 1 bit of precision is missing, meaning that `2^53` is indistinguishable from `(2^53)+1`.

Answer (score 17):

All answers are partially wrong - Maybe due the new ES6/ES7 specs - , read why:

First of all, in JavaScript, the representation of the number is **2^53 - 1** that is true for @Luke answer,
we can prove that by running `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` that will show a big number, then we do `log2` to confirm that the number of bits is the same :

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
// 9007199254740991

Math.log2(9007199254740991)
// 53
```

[image]

**However**, [Bitwise operation are calculated on 32 bits ( 4 bytes ), meaning if you exceed 32bits shifts you will start loosing bits.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Welcome to Javascript!

Comment: There are [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to workaround in the ECMA standard, and now all modern browsers are using it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 6):

All numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit (double-precision) floating point numbers.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)'s a description of the format and what values can and can't be represented with it.

Comment: Somehow it took me forever to understand why I kept seeing "53 bits of precision" but only 52 bits of storage space for the significand. That link answered the question, an implicit value of 1.