# How many bits does JavaScript use to represent a number?

Tags: javascript

How many bits does JavaScript use to represent a number?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802957/number-of-bits-in-javascript-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the specific implementation, not the language itself.

If you want to know what range of numbers is supported, then see section 8.5 (The Number Type) of [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Generally JS implementations use 64-bit double-precision floating-point numbers. Bitwise operations are performed on 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 1):

From the [referenced spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type):

> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is, 264−253+3)
> values, representing the doubleprecision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values
> as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point
> Arithmetic, except that the 9007199254740990 (that is, 253−2) distinct
> "Not-a-Number" values of the IEEE Standard are represented in
> ECMAScript as a single special NaN value. (Note that the NaN value is
> produced by the program expression NaN.) In some implementations,
> external code might be able to detect a difference between various
> Not-a-Number values, but such behaviour is implementation-dependent;
> to ECMAScript code, all NaN values are indistinguishable from each
> other.

That said be aware that when using the bit operators &, ^, >> << etc only the least significant 32 bits are used and the result is converted to a signed value.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this wall of language-spec legalese entails that *all primitive JS values fit into 8 bytes*, i.e. one does not need any tagged unions to represent them, because there is plenty of space in those 9007199254740990 distinct NaNs to both tag and represent all other primitive values.