# What is the highest number that I can store in JavaScript? I was reading a book it says that JavaScript uses a fixed number of bits to store a value

Tags: javascript, memory

JavaScript uses a fixed number of bits, 64 of them, to store a single number value. There are only so many patterns you can make with 64 bits, which means that the number of different numbers that can be represented is limited. With N decimal digits, you can represent 10^N numbers. Similarly, given 64 binary digits, you can represent 2^64 different numbers, which is about 18 quintillion (an 18 with 18 zeros after it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of bits in Javascript numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802957/number-of-bits-in-javascript-numbers)

Comment: Specifically, the largest non-big integer is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`; the largest floating point value `Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript traditionally stores numbers as a [64 bit floating point with a 52 bit mantissa](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) an 11 bit exponent and the sign is 1 bit. Effectively this means that

> Integers are accurate up to 15 digits.
> -- w3schools.com

Now with ES6 the `BigInt` proposal has been finalized, so [you can access a second type of number when dealing with integers that may be larger than 52 bits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). There also exist some libraries for operations on large numbers provided as strings.

Comment: Prefer linking to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) documentation for javascript references. see: [Why not w3schools.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com). Relevant to your answer: [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: @pilchard in this instance, I've linked to both. w3schools actually had a cleaner summary than MDN. Plus its "datedness" is desirable here